# How to check whether $_GET['id'] is set and it's not empty using php

Tags: php

Here's a php code

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    //do something
} else {
    redirect('index.php'); //redirect is a function
}
```

Now if id is set (ex: index.php?id=12) then the action is performed but if id is not set (ex: index.php?id=) this shows an error, how to overcome this...??

How to determine id is an integer and it's not empty and then perform the specific action....

Edited

Thank you all for your answers but i am still getting that error...

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) { // I implemented all these codes but still....
    $user= User::find_by_id($_GET['id']);
   // Database Classes Fetches user info from database
}
else {
    redirect('index.php'); //redirect function
}
```

If the id is 1 or greater than 1 then the script executes perfectly. ( index.php?id=1 )

But id i set id as noting i get an error i..e index.php?id=

The code should automatically redirect user to the index.php page instead of showing an error.....

ERROR : Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1

Comment: What happens when no id var is set in the query string?

Comment: By integer, do you mean PHP's datatype or do you mean any sequence of digits?

Comment: If you look at the code, it's not the datatype since @_GET allways returns a string.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should check both the set-status and the content:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['id'] ) && !empty( $_GET['id'] ) )
    // ....
```

Note that you should *not* use the value simply as it is and work with it. You should make sure that it only contains values you expect. To check for an integer, and even better to work with an integer from that on, do something like that:

```
$id = ( isset( $_GET['id'] ) && is_numeric( $_GET['id'] ) ) ? intval( $_GET['id'] ) : 0;

if ( $id != 0 )
    // id is an int != 0
else
    redirect('index.php');
```

Comment: is_int will never be true, from php.net: `Note: To test if a variable is a number or a numeric string (such as form input, which is always a string), you must use is_numeric(). `

Comment: But if i keep url as ( index.php?id= ) it shows an error....., it should redirect to index.php

Comment: @Terw: Oops, that's what happens, when I try to remember some function I don't use often.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What does the error tell you?

But this would check if it's set, and if it's an integer

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && ctype_digit($_GET['id']) && intval($_GET['id']) > 0)
```

[is_numeric @ php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

Or check out [ctype_digit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php)

Comment: `is_numeric` really doesn't cut it.

Comment: Linked to the ctype_digit function wich would just check if there are integers, updated the example to use this

Comment: But if i keep url as ( index.php?id= ) it shows an error....., it should redirect to index.php

Comment: Try this: `if(isset($_GET['id']) && ctype_digit($_GET['id']) && intval(@_GET['id']) > 0)`

Doesn't remember if you have to use the intval, long time since I used PHP

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in H:\Dev\Websites\www.demo.com\user-info.php on line 4

Comment: Just copied and pasted my code? Have an error, use $ insted of the @ in my code above :P

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($_GET['id']) && filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
```

or

```
if (!empty($_GET['id']) && ctype_digit($_GET['id']))
```

Comment: Note that integer `0` and string `"0"` are considered to be "empty" by PHP.

Comment: @Daniel: yeah, i remembered that while writing answer but I bet that he is referring to some primary key which is definitely positive integer

Comment: it's entirely possible that a primary key might be zero or negative.

Comment: @timdev A primary key for a user I doubt is negative or zero. It is possible though... Bad design nevertheless.

Comment: @Chad Scira Yes, probably bad design (basically, it suggests that negative PK values are somehow special, which is kind of like the magic number antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

> How to determine id **is an integer** and **it's not empty** and then perform the specific action....

```
if (!empty($_GET['id']) && (intval($_GET['id']) == $_GET['id'])) {
    //do something
} else {
    redirect('index.php'); //redirect is a function
}
```

The above may not be the best solution, but it should work for what you need.  It will not allow the id to be 0, and will require it to be an integer.

Comment: Will not work as you see on php.net, the @_GEt never return integers (if you doesn't specify it your self) it returns a string.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I corrected the code so that it will work for what he needs.

Comment: Sadly it didn't work for what i need...., It's should be simple if
id= (space) or id=0 it should automatically redirect user to index.php page without going further.., but it's not working... :(

Comment: Are you doing anything with `$_GET['id']` before the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

Well... If you're setting it up as an integer type variable, then you could do also this:

```
if($_GET['id'] && gettype($_GET['id']) == 'integer'){
    #do something
}else{
    #do something else
}
```

Comment: This won't work as `gettype` will always report a string type, because the GET parameters are usually not typed. Also calling `$_GET['id']` will raise an index warning when it is not set.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(isset($_GET['id']) && ctype_digit($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']>0) {
  $user= User::find_by_id($_GET['id']);
  }
else {
  redirect('index.php'); //redirect function
  }
```

Try this and this code full pill your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're just having an issue with the ?id throwing a true when you want to check if its set. Thats because it is set, but not set to a value that you would like to use.

I'm assuming the userids have to be > 0 so just do this

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0) {
    $user= User::find_by_id($_GET['id']);
} else {
    redirect('index.php'); 
}
```

Also you're prolly best cleaning the id before processing it so

```
$userID = isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0 ? (int) $_GET['id'] : 0;

if ($userID) {
    $user= User::find_by_id($userID);
} else {
    redirect('index.php'); 
}
```

Theres a lot of ways to do it, personally I prefer this. It makes your code look a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check multiple times for every case possible: what if id is not set or empty? what if id is set but it is not a digit? what if 'id' key does not exist at all in GET request?

I had similar situation. I was sending two vars with GET, one digit: 'id' and another one was string which was a name: 'state' ... I solved it by checking all possible conditions.